# BDMO 2016 Regional - Geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> $ \triangle PQR \ $ is an isosceles triangle where $PQ = PR. $ $X$ is a point on the circumcircle of
>   $ΔPQR $, such that it lies on the arc $QR$. The
>   normal drawn from the point $P$ on $XR$ intersects $XR$ at point $Y.$ Prove that $$QX + YR = XY.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflect the $R$ across line $PY$ in to $Z$. So $Z\in XR$ and $YZ = YR$ and $$PZ = PR = PQ$$

[image]

Sp we have to prove that $QX = XZ$. Since $$\angle XZP = \pi-\angle RZP =  \pi-\angle XRP = \angle XQP$$ and $$\angle QXP = \angle QRP =  \angle RQP = \angle ZXP$$ we see that triangle $XQP$ is congruent to triangle $XZP$ (s.a.s.) and we are done.

Comment: I think the reason of congruence is AAS instead.

Comment: Could be also ASA @Mick

Comment: I mean at least not (s. a. s.).

Comment: And why not @Mick

Comment: In your proof, you have mentioned 2 pairs of equal angles (and a common side). That means the reason to be quoted is either AAS or ASA.

Comment: The common side is needed to be proved it is congruent, there for you can not use ASA for these triple. But you can use ASA for side XP or for side PZ. However I don't know whatAAS means.

Comment: The first A is from $\angle XZP = ... = \angle XQP$. The sencond A is from $\angle QXP = ... = \angle ZXP$. The last S comes from either quoting $XP = XP$ or $QP = ... = ZP$.